# Clustered Columnstore index internal data structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Where can I see internal data structure for clustered cloumnstore index? I do see architecture of columnar data structure, delta row store and periodic process which will move delta row store to column store

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx

I need to understand more about internal data structure for columnar data in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

[Niko Neugebauer - Columnstore](http://www.nikoport.com/columnstore/)

Niko Neugebauer has done a whole series on columnstore indexes and how they work.